# Flutter and OpenGL ES?

Tags: flutter

I'm Android developer, my app use kotlin and opengl es 3.0, you can think of it as a simple 2D photo edit app, I want make it run on windows,web,ios and macos, so I learn flutter, Because in consideration phase, I would like to ask experienced person, if Flutter supports the use of OpengL ES on multiple platforms? If not, is it still necessary to use platform-specific graphical interface language for each platform while using flutter?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment this is what we have.

> [Can I build 3D (OpenGL) apps with Flutter?](https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/faq#can-i-build-3d-opengl-apps-with-flutter) Today we don’t support for
> 3D via OpenGL ES or similar. We have long-term plans to expose an
> optimized 3D API, but right now we’re focused on 2D.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32809540)